# How to store tippy tooltips in a data.frame and render them through reactable?

Tags: r, shiny, reactable, tippyjs

To bypass [this issue](https://github.com/glin/reactable/issues/111), I am trying to store tippy tooltips in a data.frame column and render them in reactable without using the cell attribute in colDef. I tried the following example to show tooltips with dogs pictures when hovering on the dog name, unsuccessfully. Any suggestions?

```
library(shiny); library(tidyverse); library(tippy)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Reactable and pop-ups"),
    reactableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
df <- data.frame(dog_name=c("Fred", "Joe"),
                 dog_pic=c("https://images.pexels.com/photos/406014/pexels-photo-406014.jpeg", "https://images.pexels.com/photos/39317/chihuahua-dog-puppy-cute-39317.jpeg")
) %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(dog_name=tippy(dog_name, div(dog_pic)) %>% htmltools:::as.character.shiny.tag.list()) %>% 
  ungroup()
output$table <- renderReactable(reactable(df, 
                                          columns = list(
                                            dog_name=colDef(html = TRUE, name="Dog"),
                                            dog_pic=colDef(show = FALSE))))
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```